# Call to undefined relationship [relation] on model [App/Model]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

#### Environment:

- Laravel Version: 5.8.29
- PHP Version `$ php --version`: PHP 7.2.24 (cli)
- Database Driver & Version `$ mysql --version`: mysql Ver 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
- Doctrine/Inflector: 1.4

`composer.json`

```
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2.24",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "doctrine/inflector": "1.4.0"
    },
```

---

#### Problem Statement:

Below relation is working on localhost but throwing error on Server. This seems like issue is with **[Doctrine/Inflector](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/32730)** package.

> Note: Its working on Localhost but not on server setup.

```
$ php artisan tinker
>>> $borrower = Borrower::with('application')->find(2);

PHP Deprecated:  The "Doctrine/Common/Inflector/Inflector::pluralize" method is deprecated and will be dropped in doctrine/inflector 2.0. Please update to the new Inflector API. in /path/vendor/doctrine/inflector/lib/Doctrine/Common/Inflector/Inflector.php on line 264
Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/RelationNotFoundException with message 'Call to undefined relationship [application] on model [App/Borrower].'
```

---

##### Models

`App\Borrower.php`

```
<?php  

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Borrower extends Authenticatable
{

    protected $table = 'borrowers';

    public function application()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Application', 'borrower_id', 'borrower_id');
    }
```

`App\Models\Application.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Application extends Model
{
    
    protected $table = 'applications';

    public function borrower()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Borrower', 'borrower_id', 'borrower_id');
    }
```

##### Table

---

`borrowers`

```
| borrower_id | fname  | email                  |
|-------------|--------|------------------------|
| 1           | John   | john@peakyblinder.com  |
| 2           | Thomas | tommy@peakyblinder.com |
```

`applications`

```
| id | name       | borrower_id |
|----|------------|-------------|
| 1  | Birmingham | 1           |
| 2  | BBC        | 1           |
```

---

Comment: Are you sure the code is the same in both environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the doctrine inflector method, maybe you need upgrade it otherwise other solution is upgrade your version of Laravel to at least 7.x.

Try to upgrade your version of your packages in your command line:

```
composer update
```

and then install the new doctrine/inflector:

```
composer require doctrine/inflector
```

Comment: I've require `"doctrine/inflector": "1.4"` but not working.